# xpath - select a node value if another node value exists

Tags: xpath

I have several nodes (see below). I know how to select specific nodes which have a certain attribute. But in this case I would like to import the "file_url" value of the media objects that belong to the group "narrowImage".

```
<media_object>

 <media_object>
  <file_id>5175967</file_id>
  <group>wideImage</group>
  <file_url>http://www.mysite.com/image1.jpg</file_url>
 </media_object>

 <media_object>
  <file_id>5175968</file_id>
  <group>wideImage</group>
  <file_url>http://www.mysite.com/image2.jpg</file_url>
 </media_object>

 <media_object>
  <file_id>5175969</file_id>
  <group>narrowImage</group>
  <file_url>http://www.mysite.com/image3.jpg</file_url>
 </media_object>

</media_object>
```

In the above case i would only need the value "http://www.mysite.com/image3.jpg"

any xpath expert out there who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[group = 'narrowImage']/file_url
```

This selects any `file_url` element that is a "grand-child" of the top element in the XML document, and whose parent has a `group` child-element whose string value is `'narrowImage'`.

Comment: thank you dimitre, i didnt quite know which keywords to use in my search, helped me out a bunch

Comment: @WilliamLekatompessy: You are welcome. You can use The XPath Visualizer tool for learning XPath the fun way: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use:

```
//media_object[group='narrowImage']/file_url
```

This should select every **media_object** in your file (regardless of the level) then filter them based on **group='narrowImage'** then give you the **file_url** child.